# Autocomplete searchbox for files (images); is it possible, how?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to give the user an autocomplete inputfield (with image in result) which searches a folder, /devices, filled with GIF's "AAU01-010.gif", "AAU01-020.gif".

**I want them to be able to search on the name of the files.** 
Since i couldn't find anything on the internet, is this possible, if so, how?!

P.S. I took underlying code from another example online, still need to change it to my needs
    $(function() {

```
    $("#my_ac").autocomplete({
        source: [
            {
                value: "Tom Hanks",
                label: "Tom Hanks",
                description: "Actor",
                image: "hanks.png"
            },
            {
                value: "Termionator 2",
                label: "Termionator 2",
                description: "Movie",
                image: "terminator.png"
            }
        ],
        minLength: 1
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var inner_html = '<a><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.image + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.label + '</div><div class="description">' + item.description + '</div></div></a>';
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<h3>Ref_Devices</h3>
      <div style="height:300px;">
      <input type="text" id="my_ac"/>
      <div class="list_item_container">
    <div class="image"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="label"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Should be possible but you need to have a server side script as your source that returns an array of files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a server side script and update your existing JavaScript to handle a JSON response from the controller for example using AJAX. I will update this answer with a basic PHP script.

```
<?php

    $sQuery = $_GET['search']; # string to search
    $aResults = array(); # empty results array

    # loop through directory containing images
    if($handle = opendir('./images')) {
        while(false !== ($sFileName = readdir($handle))) {

            # blacklist particular names to exclude from search
            if(in_array($sFileName,array('.','..'))) continue;

            # if we find a result, add it to the array of results
            if(stristr($sFileName,$sQuery)) $aResults[] = $sFileName;
        }
    }

    # return jSON encoded array
    exit(json_encode($aResults));

?>
```

The above is an example of the PHP you could use to get your results.

Comment: I'm however terrible with AJAX/JSON and have no idea how to combine this with my input box, just a bit more tips/code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if i should let the php script do the searching, or let the autocomplete function do this, because i could also just request a list of files with php, an then let autocomplete do a search on it..? There's about 2300 Files so i don't know what would be the best performance-wise?

Comment: @Firebirdz I would suggest you let the PHP controller do the processing as otherwise people could view the names of every single file you have regardless of what they search and every time they search they would have to download the entire list of 2300+ file-names. Alternatively, I guess you could just load the list in once to JavaScript but the usual method would be to let the controller do the work. I would suggest googling for a solution to pull the results with Autocomplete as I am not that familiar with Autocomplete.